# Consuming Cloud Functions for Firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, google-cloud-functions

I've written a cloud function for Firebase using Node.

```
exports.fetchStudents = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return admin.database().ref('Student').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var students = snapshot.val();
        response.send(students)
        console.log(students)
    });
});
```

I've deployed it over Firebase Server and at console, I'm getting desired values. 
I wan't to use this function in my iOS app. I really don't know how to consume this functions in my iOS app.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've achieved this, it's quite easy. What you need is to hit the url provided at CLI after successful upload of  function.

> **Function URL** (helloWorld): https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld.

replace project-id by your project's id.

```
let url = URL(string:  "https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/fetchStudents")!

let urlReq = URLRequest(url: url)

let students = Alamofire.request(urlReq).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
         switch response.result{
           case .success(let value):
              completion(JSON(value), nil)
           case .failure(let error):
              completion(nil, String(describing: error))
        }
     }
```