# How to retrieve all FCM tokens from server side to subscribe users to a topic?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

### Background

I posted a question a few days ago and gained some insight: [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236786/how-to-programmatically-subscribe-users-to-firestore-topics). However, I did a poor job asking the question so I still don't know how I can retrieve all the users FCM tokens in order to use something like this: [Subscribe the client app to a topic](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple?hl=en#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic). This is also listed under the Server Environments documentation. My clients are on the **iOS platform.**

This function requires the client FCM tokens to be in a list to iterate over and subscribe each client to a topic to later be used for push notifications. Also I have almost 3,000 users which is more than the 1,000 device limit noted in the documentation.

I was also directed to some server documentation by another clever answer: [Manage relationship maps for multiple app instances](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances). However, after reading through the material I still believe I need an array of client registration tokens to use this method. My analysis could be totally incorrect. I am quite ignorant since I'm very young and have a ton to learn.

I also tried to get the client FCM tokens with [Bulk retrieve user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#bulk_retrieve_user_data), but this does not have access to device tokens.

### Question

How cant I obtain all of the users registration tokens to provide to this function:

```
var registrationTokens = [];

admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
  });
```

Furthermore, if I have over 1000 users, let's say 3000. How can I make separate request to subscribe everyone and not surpass the 1000 device per request limit?

#### Additional question on device groups

I've been trying to accomplish a "Global" push notification by sending messages with topics. Is sending messages to device groups perhaps a better approach?

> send different messages to different phone models, your servers can add/remove registrations to the appropriate groups and send the appropriate message to each group

After reading the documentation they both seem adequately to accomplish my goal, however, device groups allows the server to more accurately send messages to specified devices. Are one of these methods a better practice? Or for my case is the difference trivial?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about tokens here is that they can change at any time like:

- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

so even if you save them some where then try to register them all at once, some of them may not be valid at that time.

better way to do this is form your registaration token on your client side (IOS):

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
  } else if let token = token {
    print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
    self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text  = "Remote FCM registration token: \(token)"
  }
}
```

then monitor changes on this token:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

  let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

and send changes to server (which can be any type of servers here) like Firebase Functions with Nodejs. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901274/consuming-cloud-functions-for-firebase-in-ios) to know how to post a request to Firebase HTTP functions. Then, you can use the same code that you have posted here within that function to register the token to the topic.

This way, you will never exceed that limit and you keep track of all the users' registeration tokens changes.